# How to get the hash of the commit in which a deleted line was added?

Tags: git

When doing `git diff`, the old line and now line are shown next to each other, e.g:

```
-    @principal.connections.joins(:contact_infos)
+    @principal.connections.joins(:node)
```

Is there any command, or parameter, which will cause git to print the hash of the commit in which the deleted line was added?

For example, if the line `@principal.connections.joins(:contact_infos)` was added in the commit `foo1234` and changed to `@principal.connections.joins(:node)` in the commit `bar1234`, then is there a way to get:

```
- foo1234   @principal.connections.joins(:contact_infos)
+    @principal.connections.joins(:node)
```

When doing `git diff`, or another command which will give a list of deleted lines and the hash in which they were added?

Closest I came was `git blame` but that only gives hashes for lines which are currently in the file, not ones which were modified / deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `git blame` the old version of a file, typically I use a parent commit reference. E.g.:

```
$ git blame git-mergetool.sh
f8750a0e (Junio C Hamano   2012-08-22 22:33:15 -0700 356)       if test "$merge_keep_backup" = "true"
f8750a0e (Junio C Hamano   2012-08-22 22:33:15 -0700 357)       then
f8750a0e (Junio C Hamano   2012-08-22 22:33:15 -0700 358)               mv -- "$BACKUP" "$MERGED.orig"
f8750a0e (Junio C Hamano   2012-08-22 22:33:15 -0700 359)       else
f8750a0e (Junio C Hamano   2012-08-22 22:33:15 -0700 360)               rm -- "$BACKUP"
f8750a0e (Junio C Hamano   2012-08-22 22:33:15 -0700 361)       fi
```

Then if you use `git show` and discover that `f8750a0e` was all style fixes you might want to blame the previous version with something like:

```
$ git blame f8750a0e^ git-mergetool.sh
44c36d1c (Charles Bailey   2008-02-21 23:30:02 +0000 276)     if test "$merge_keep_backup" = "true"; then
b3ea27e4 (Charles Bailey   2008-02-21 23:30:34 +0000 277)       mv -- "$BACKUP" "$MERGED.orig"
44c36d1c (Charles Bailey   2008-02-21 23:30:02 +0000 278)     else
44c36d1c (Charles Bailey   2008-02-21 23:30:02 +0000 279)       rm -- "$BACKUP"
44c36d1c (Charles Bailey   2008-02-21 23:30:02 +0000 280)     fi
```

So in your case you can use `git blame bar1234^ file` and the line you care about should be labelled with `foo1234`. Note that as in my example you may find the lines have moved around a lot between the current version, the version where the line was last changed and that commit's immediate parent.

Comment: `you can use git blame bar1234 and the line you care about should be labelled with foo1234` - Unfortunately that doesn't seem to happen. When I do `git blame 1234 file.txt`, the line I care about has `bar1234` next to it instead of `foo1234`

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Sorry, my fault. I've just edited that into my suggested command. It was correct in my "real" example.

Comment: No it wasn't your fault, I just missed it. This is awesome, you've saved me a lot of work.

Comment: @CharlesBailey how to find the same in github. I mean finding the commit which added the line which is been deleted by the current commit